# MongoDB Storage Engine

Tags: mongodb-3.0, storage-engine

How can I change the storage engine of MongoDB permanently so that I don't have to run *mongod* without having to specify the storage engine every time? I am using shell version 3.2.7 on Windows 7 32-bit. I got an error that said:

> 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is
>   not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different
>   storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating.

Also does anyone know how to cleanly shutdown the server when I am done working? I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but it causes an error, then I have to empty the data folder to get the process to start again.

Comment: One problem per question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that in the [`storage.config`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine) setting within your YAML configuration file.

Example:

```
storage:
  dbPath: d:\data\db
  engine: mmapv1
```

If you're not already starting your MongoDB service using a configuration file, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition) for the details on how do to that for Windows.

Comment: Worked like a charm.